# Chainlink Quick Start problems connecting to the database?

Tags: chainlink

I have gone through the AWS Chainlink quickstart successfully. I disabled the ssl certificate and decided to use TCP enabled. The Chainlink node did not launch on intial deployment. I used the .sh files to create .api, .password, .env

I run the run script but get this error

opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=/tmp user= database=`: dial error (dial unix /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or directory)

I have also gone through the step on the Chainlink docs to enable https connections, and have configured the tls ports in the .env file.

I thought for sure it was the tls blocking me from the database. But still I get this error

Here is my DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@writerendpointofcluster:5432/databasename

I used the writer endpoint of the cluster.

I don't know what to try next. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question seems to be related to documentation. In this case, I suggest you to create an issue on the documentation repo instead of stackoverflow.
If this is not the case, your question needs to be clearer, focused on the technology, not the docs.
You said "I run the run script but get this error"
What script?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the password for the database. There are certain characters that throw an error.

The instructions on the AWS Chainlink quickstart on the database password characters that are prohibited is not an exhaustive list.

In regards to AWS Chainlink quickstart, you can use the "!" as the symbol requirement for the database password.

We are putting together a list of characters that throw an error, so far we have #, ^, %, $ symbols that prevents you from connecting to the database.

*please comment which symbol gave you an error and I can add it to the list

Answer (score 1):

In addition to !, * and _ can be used as the symbol requirement for the database password.

The following characters also lead to an error: <, >, @, =. This is due to some special characters requiring percent encoding, as discussed on this AWS Chainlink QuickStart [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-chainlinklabs-chainlink-node/issues/23#issuecomment-970486800).